# Virtual screening lib

Tags: computational-chemistry

I had a quick question on virtual libraries. I'm hoping to perform a virtual screen using a library that contains very small, soluble compounds - think glycerol and smaller (<100MW). As far as I can tell, the majority of virtual libraries contain mostly larger, drug-like compounds. Is anyone aware of any libraries that might contain ideally 10,000+ or so of these tiny soluble compounds?

If not, any idea how difficult it might be to construct a custom virtual library enriched for these compounds?

Thank you!!

Comment: Just a guess: COSMO-RS based calculations are pretty good for most small molecules, as far as I know.